# Mongo DB Driver pre and post collection update methods

Tags: go, mongo-go-driver

Need to handle pre and post collection changes by overriding default methods. How to achieve it with mongo-go-driver ?

Comment: There are no update hooks. How could it be? Documents can be updated in ways other than just the Go driver, would you expect the server to call you back on each update?

Comment: Im looking something similar like signals in django